# CSS cursor is not changing appearance

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to create a code to change users cursor to the custom cursor( cursor.cur ) i applied it to the body so that when people hover over it will change to cursor.cur but the cursor does not change.

```
<html>
<style>
body:hover
{
cursor: url('C:\Users\b  n\Downloads\cursor.cur'), auto;
}
</style>
<body>
<p>blah blah blah...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a relative path instead of a absolute path for your cursor file

Answer (score 0):

Try this code I have downloaded png cursor image you can replace it with your own. single quotes doesn't matter you can remove it or add it just need to change the path.

```
<html>
    <style>
        body{cursor: url('../Downloads/icons8-cursor-80.png'), auto;}
    </style>
    <body>
        <p>blah blah blah...</p>
    </body>
</html>
```